# Add a String to an Array

Tags: c, arrays, string

How can I create a string array in the C language?  Its length should be five, and a loop should be used to get input from the user to fill the array with.  Finally, I should print all string values in the array to the user.

Comment: C or C++? These are separate languages... Also, what have you tried so far? This looks like homework, and while we'll help you out, we won't do the entire assignment for you. You learn nothing that way.

Comment: Homework? Read the [C info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) and the [C++ info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info).

Comment: It sounds like you mean an array of five strings. Remember that in C, a string is itself an array of characters; so you need an array of arrays (or pointers, but that's probably beyond what you've learned for now). Does that help? As the comments say, you probably won't find anyone here who will just write the code for you. However, if you are willing to make some effort and show the code you've written, people will help you find the errors in it.

Comment: I really hope you actually try to learn to code, otherwise you'll end up as one of the "programmers" that don't actually know how to code and give us all a bad reputation.

Answer (score 4):

A string in C is really an array of characters. If you want to make a character array of length 256, you can do it like this:

```
char my_var[256];
```

You can read in a string of length 128 from standard input like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
// ...
fgets(my_var,128,stdin);
```

You can print out a string like this:

```
printf("String is: %s",my_var);
```

A string is stored in the array character-by-character, and ends with the null character '\0'. Thus if my_var holds `{'c','a','n','\0','s'}`, then my_var looks like "can". But if the string does not end until it sees a null character. So if you fill a string character-by-character, you must append the '\0'. If you fill it with something like `fgets`, the null character is appended automatically. Also, note that '\0' is equal to zero.

Those are just easy howtos to get you started. As pmg said, we aren't here to do your homework for you, just give you tips. Look up fgets, printf, "strings in C", etc. If you get stuck, you can come back and ask a more specific question!

Comment: Hmmm @bo perhaps mentioning the null terminator would be appropriate

Answer (score 0):

try this for c,

```
string FileMeasure="Hello FILE!"
int TempNumOne=FileMeasure.size();
char Filename[100];
for (int a=0;a<=TempNumOne;a++)
    {
        Filename[a]=FileMeasure[a];
    }
```

and try this for java,

```
String[] words = {"ace", "boom", "crew", "dog", "eon"};  

List<String> wordList = Arrays.asList(words);  

for (String e : wordList)  
{  
     System.out.println(e); 
}
```